# Search Box using Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, extract

I’m new to GUIs on python!!!! 
I’ve got a question, I’m basically opening a .txt file and searching through the lines for a string; this string is found after approximately every 100 lines.
My aim is basically to have a GUI that opens the .txt (using a GUI dialog box) then have another dialog that “searches” through this file (for the given string)...and exports the the (100 or so) lines from one file in a new .txt file!
I’d appreciate your help!!!

Here is the code:

```
*import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
select_file = tk.Tk()  # Dialog box to prompt user for the file.
select_file.withdraw()
in_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
#print(in_path)
inspect_log = open(in_path, "r")  # Open event_log.log for read only access.*
```

Comment: now read file and search what you need - and when you will have result then you have to  decide if you want to use [Text()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) or [Listbox()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) in main window `tk.Tk()` to display it.

Comment: You've told us what you want but you haven't actually asked a question. What part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: @furas thanks for the info!! :)

Comment: @BryanOakley point!! so basically how can i get a GUI to prompt the user to type a string to search through the .txt file? Not too keen on using Text() or Listbox() though!! :|

Answer (score 1):

You can use `simpledialog.askstring()` to ask for pattern and later you can put `Text()` or `Listbox()` or `Label()`  in main window `Tk()` with result

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import simpledialog

select_file = tk.Tk()  # Dialog box to prompt user for the file.
select_file.withdraw()

# read

in_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
inspect_log = open(in_path)  # Open event_log.log for read only access.*
data = inspect_log.read()

# search

pattern = simpledialog.askstring('Search', 'What to search?')

results = []
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if pattern in line:
        results.append(line)
results = "".join(results)

# save results

output_file = open("output.txt", "w")
output_file.write(results)
output_file.close()

# display result

text = tk.Text(select_file)
text.pack()

text.insert('end', results)

button = tk.Button(select_file, text="Close", command=select_file.destroy)
button.pack()

select_file.deiconify()
select_file.mainloop()
```